# Terminal becomes unresponsive when I use “tail –f catalina.out”

Tags: terminal

Setup: Mac OSX 10.6.8, Terminal 2.1.2 (273.1)

My Terminal sometimes becomes unresponsive after I enter certain commands. An example is when I put a tail on the catalina.out file though it happens at other times as well.

An example of the steps I take when im putting a tail on.

I go to the startup folder

```
cd /Applications/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/bin
```

Enter the start command

```
sh startup.sh
```

Go to my logs folder

```
cd /Applications/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/logs
```

And put a tail on the catalina.out file

```
tail -f catalina.out
```

This all works fine and the terminal window displays the processes as they are being used. However, if I try to type something else in Terminal it becomes unresponsive. If I press the Up or Down arrow to get list the previous commands all I get is for UP is "^[[A" and "^[[B" for DOWN.

When I type e.g. `"cd .."` and press enter nothing happens

Why does Terminal become unresponsive and how can I make it execute my commands? At the moment I have to quite Terminal each time this happened which is a bit annoying.

Comment: When you are tailing file with `-f` flag, `tail` start waiting for appended data from this file. That why nothing happens. Actually, answer is in `man tail`.

Comment: I assumed that since he was following the file it would keep spurting out rubbish into his typing, and when you are watching a file in real time you CANNOT enter commands into the same window.  I must be wrong as you took the time to down vote my answer too!  But please explain why I'm wrong as "man tail" explains pretty much what I've already said.

Comment: Hi there

I took a look at `man tail` and I now understand that Terminal is waiting for additional data to be appended to the input.

But how do I get out of it so I can use Terminal again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use tail -f

Instead when you want to run it instead of

```
sh startup.sh
```

run:

```
sh catalina.sh run
```

It will log everything to the window.

OR you can just open another terminal and do your tail -f from there!

Comment: Hi

I tried `sh catalina.sh run` and this runs Terminal and may be useful in future. However I am looking for the stream of information about which files are being interacted with. `sh catalina.sh run` does not provide this so I must use `sh startup.sh`

However this is not the issue. My problem is that Terminal becomes unresponsive at different times. Using `tail -f catalina.out` is just one example of when it. It also happens with other commands.

As I state above I am looking for some method or making Terminal responsive again when this happens so I don’t have to restart it each time.

Comment: ctrl-c should drop you out of tail and return everything to normal.